# How to open second UI Datepicker on selecting the date of first one only not on close?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I´m trying to add some functionality to a form with JQuery UI´s Datepicker. 
1. when i select a date in the start date picker it should show the next date in end datepicker.
2. when i select the end date  as less than startdate it should show the previous date of enddate and show a start datepicker. 
 I have clear button in the datepicker when i click on the clear button in start datepicker it open the end datepicker. I do not want like this. I want to open the end date picker by selecting the date on start date

```
$( "#start").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(addclearbutton, 1 );
    },
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
    onChangeMonthYear: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(addclearbutton, 1 );
    },
    onSelect: function (dateStr,input) { 
        daterangevalidation(dateStr,input);
    },
    onClose:function() {
        $("#end").datepicker('show');  
    }                
});    

$( "#end").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(addclearbutton, 1 );
    },
    beforeShowDay: highlightDays,  
    onChangeMonthYear: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(addclearbutton, 1 );
    },
    onSelect: function (dateStr,input) { 
        daterangevalidation(dateStr,input);
    }
});
```